# D3.js Brush & Zoom to Rescale Y-Axis By Zoomed Range's Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What would be the most elegant way to autoscale Y-axis range/domain according to zoome range's values, when modifying this demo?

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

There must be some *d3-zoom* methods that can accomplish accessing zoomed range's values, but haven't yet figured out which those would be...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what's the *most elegant way* (until someone shows it). However, here is my solution.

First, we filter the data according to the zoom:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(d=>d.date > x.domain()[0] && d.date < x.domain()[1]);
```

Then, we change the y domain accordingly:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(filteredData, function(d) { return d.price; })]);
```

Here is the demo, zoom in and out to see the y axis changing:
https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/9f8c2edcb5950cac61f1bc3873886ec5/

This other version avoids NaN when you zoom in too much:
https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/56fa7fe37596f753db74fdad58ba6725/

PS: I had to move some functions (due to scope issues) in order to access `data` inside the function `zoomed`.

Comment: You could also do the same thing in the brushed() function so that the y axis rescales as you brush.